# Unable to set volume for mongodb logs in docker container

Tags: mongodb, docker, containers

My docker mongo images

```
REPOSITORY   TAG       IMAGE ID       CREATED      SIZE
mongo        latest    f03be0dc25f8   2 days ago   448MB
```

My container command

```
docker run -it --name c1_mongo -p 37017:27017 -v /var/mongo/data/c1_mongo:/data/db -v /var/mongo/config/c1_mongo/mongod.conf.orig:/etc/mongod.conf.orig -v /var/mongo/logs/c1_mongo:/var/log/mongodb mongo -f /etc/mongod.conf.orig
```

The error I am getting

```
{"t":{"$date":"2021-03-29T11:00:02.967Z"},"s":"F",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":20574,   "ctx":"main","msg":"Error during global initialization","attr":{"error":{"code":38,"codeName":"FileNotOpen","errmsg":"Failed to open /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log"}}}
```

1. I have successfully set the volume for my data directory inside the container to my host
2. I have successfully set the volume for my config file inside the container to my host
3. Setting the volume for the log is failing.

When I change my config file in the host and run the container so my all changes get reflected in my config file in the container. And data in my container's /data/db directory is being synced to my respective folder in the host.

Just like my data if being stored in my host. I want my logs to be stored on my host as well.

Note: volume mapping showing the directories of both host and container.

Please Help!

Comment: Can a solution be to add ```systemLog.destination``` to your ```mongod.conf``` and set this to a directory you mount from the host?

Answer (score 4):

This issue can be resolved using the following steps.

> 1. Run the container without mounting the volume which is causing the issue.
> 2. Go into container bash and check the folder permission on which you are facing issue in my case it is /var/log/mongodb
> 3. Now check the owner of the folder.
> 4. run "cat passwd" in container shell and find that owner you found in last step and note the id against it could be(999 or 1000 etc).
> 5. Now exit the container, stop it, remove it.
> 6. Now on your host log path which in my case is /var/mongo/data/c1_mongo
> 7. Change the owner of c1_mongo folder to, "chown -R 999:999 c1_mongo" (999 is the id you found in step 4)
> 8. Now run your container again.